# DDD - chosing right Aggregate Root

Tags: oop, architecture, domain-driven-design, software-design

I have a really simple domain. Users play sport betting in private leagues. For each fixture user needs to select expected result and exact score for set of matches. If user wants to see other users bets before the fixture starts, he can freeze his bets. There are some business rules that must be fulfilled:

Bets cannot be changed if less than 30 minutes left to the first fixture match starts.
Bets cannot be frozen if not all matches results are provided.
Bets cannot be changed if they have been already frozen.
At the end of the day, module receives a notification with finished matches results. At this moment all bets should be resolved, points calculated, granted and the league table updated.

My initial idea for Aggregate Root was FixtureBets with methods updateBets, freeze and resolveBets. Resolving bets would attach points to each resolved match and publish BetsResolved domain event, which would trigger league table recalculation.

The main problem is that it would publish BetsResolved event separately for each league member and the table would be recalculated multiple times. The league table can be inconsistent for some short time. Also I would like to track standings tendency(upward/falling) for users, so table recalculation would need to happen once. Also performance-wise its not the best solution. I suppose LeagueTable should be another Aggregate Root here. Maybe it should wait for all users points updates and then recalculate standings and tendencies?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the idea would be to introduce some kind of [orchestration/orchestrator](https://ddd-practitioners.com/home/glossary/orchestration/) (in theory it can be `FixtureBets` itself, or separate one) which will aggregate the results of processing `BetsResolved` by league members and when all finish the processing will publish the aggregate message. For example the pipeline can look like the following:

[image]

Similar approach can be used with `LeagueTable` as orchestrator. `FixtureBets` will publish two kinds of messages - `MemberBetsResolved` (per member) and `BetsStartedCalculating` for `LeagueTable` which will aggregate `MemberBetsCalculated`.